# Angularjs push work only when i refresh the url

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope

I want to push an element in my view, the problem is that element appears in the view only when I refresh the url.
this is the function:

```
$scope.add = function(index) {
     $scope.projects = [];

     function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {

     console.log(error, stdout, stderr);

     if (error == null) {

         $scope.db.insert('project', {
             "idProject": $scope.idProject,
             "name": $scope.ProjectName,
             'path': directory
         }).
         then(function(results) {

                 $scope.projects.push({
                     "idProject": idp,
                     "name": namep,
                     'path': directory
                 });


             }
             exec("  cd " + "path", puts);
         )
     }
```

### the html :

```
<a style="background: #AFAFAF"> <i ng-click="remove(project.id)" class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o"></i> {{project.name}}</a>
<input class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()" />
```

Comment: $scope.add is incomplete here, where is puts called?

Comment: Puts  is the callback  of  the  exec  function :  exec("  cd " +"path" , puts);

Comment: But `exec()` is inside the `puts`. Where is the original call of `puts`?

Comment: exec  is not   inside the puts  in my orginal code , i made a mistake  when i copy paste the code ,i  edit  the code.

Comment: What does `db` refer to?

Comment: $scope.db = $webSql.openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'DB Test', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

Comment: Post a fiddle and you'll get help.